# LinkedList - Creating function that takes a value, creates a node, and add it to end of list

Tags: javascript, linked-list

This is the pseudocode we have to build the LL from:

```
FUNCTION push(element)
CREATE node
SET node.value TO element
SET node.next TO null

IF the head node does not exist
THEN SET head to node
ELSE
SET current to head
SET current.next to node
END IF
END FUNCTION
```

The pseudocode itself has an error in it as well.

Below is my attempt to follow that, but right now it's pointing
to the { right after value in the push function.

```
let head = null,
last,
node,
current,
value = element;

const linkedList = () => {
 let node = new Node(value);

 push(value) {
   if(head === null) {
       head = last = node;
   } else {
       last.next = node;
       last = node;
   }
  }
 }
```

Error : push(value) { <----- This curly bracket is throwing the error. Unexpected token.

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: "The pseudocode itself has an error in it as well" - but you are not going to tell us what it is?

Comment: What does "` it's pointing to the { `" mean?? Are you getting a compiler error? If so, tell us what it says. How can we help you otherwise?  And which `{` ? There are several

Comment: This is an exercise that I'm doing

Comment: "The pseudocode itself has an error in it as well". Yes, the instructions say that they purposefully put in something that doesn't work and you have to figure that out

Comment: Added last line to clarify where the error is

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beside the syntax error, you have a logical error as well. You need to treat the head node different from any other node and set the head property to node if not set, but if set, then assign to the last node the next node.

If you no head node, you can not set the last node, because there is actually no one.

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.last = null;
    }
    push(value) {
        var node = new Node(value);
        if (!this.head) {
            this.head = node;
        } else {
            this.last.next = node;
        }
        this.last = node;
    }
}

var ll = new LinkedList;

ll.push(10);
console.log(ll);

ll.push(11);
console.log(ll);

ll.push(12);
console.log(ll);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

With check for an already inserted value.

```js
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.value = value;
        this.next = null;
    }
}

class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
        this.last = null;
    }
    push(value) {
        var node = new Node(value),
            temp = this.head;
        
        while (temp) {
            if (temp.value === value) return;
            temp = temp.next;
        }

        if (!this.head) {
            this.head = node;
        } else {
            this.last.next = node;
        }
        this.last = node;
    }
}

var ll = new LinkedList;

ll.push(10);
console.log(ll);

ll.push(11);
console.log(ll);

ll.push(12);
console.log(ll);

ll.push(11);
console.log(ll);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: do you have a moment to chat about linkedlists?

Comment: i don't know if i have the capabilities to create a chat room or how it works

Comment: just ask here, and if the comments becomes more, the chat opportunity appears.

Comment: I need make an unsorted singly linked list and remove all duplicates from the linked list.
Example
Input: a -> c -> d -> d -> a
Output: a -> c -> d

Comment: then you need to iterate for `head` node to the end (`next` is `null`) and then insert the new node if not found.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/184385/discussion-between-cjl85-and-nina-scholz).

Answer (score 1):

And since we are at it.
Here is a version where you can insert append and remove nodes in ES6. No last node thougth since that would ruin the beauty of it. :)

```
class Node {
    constructor(value) {
        this.prev = null;
        this.next = null;
        this.value = value === undefined? null : value;
        this.list = null;
    }
    remove() {
        let prev = this.prev;
        let next = this.next;
        if (prev) {
            prev.next = next;
        }
        if (next) {
            next.prev = prev;
        }
        return this;
    }
    insert(node) {
        let prev = this.prev;
        if (prev) {
            prev.next = node;
            node.prev = prev;
        }
        this.prev = node;
        node.next = this;
    }
    append(node) {
        let next = this.next;
        if (next) {
            next.prev = node;
            node.next = next;
        }
        this.next = node;
        node.prev = this;
    }
}
class LinkedList {
    constructor() {
        this.head = null;
    }
    get last() {
        return this.list.length > 0 ? this.list[this.list.length] : null;
    }
    get values() {
        let node = this.head;
        let values = [];
        while(node) {
            values.push(node.value);
            node = node.next;
        };
        return values;
    }

    push(node) {
        node.prev = null;
        node.next = null;
        if (this.head) {
            this.head.prev = node;
            node.next = this.head;
        }
        this.head = node;
    }
    find(v) {
        let node = this.head;
        let fn = v;
        if (!(v instanceof Function)) fn = (el) => el.value === v;
        while(node && !fn(node)) {node = node.next;};
        return node;
    }
    forEach(fn) {
        let node = this.head;
        while(node) {fn(node); node = node.next;};
    }
}
```

Usable like so:

```
let ll = new LinkedList();
let n1= new Node(1);
let n2= new Node(2);
let n3= new Node(3);
ll.push(n1);
ll.push(n2);
ll.find(1).append(n3);
console.log(ll.values);
ll.find(3).remove();
console.log(ll.values);
ll.find(2).append(n3);
console.log(ll.values);
```